# Loading an X509Certificate2 in Mono throws CryptographicException "Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate"

Tags: c#, mono, x509certificate2

I'm writing a small utility on Windows that will eventually need to run on both Windows and Linux (under Mono).  In it, I'm loading a certificate from a file specified by user input, which works just fine in Windows.  However, when I go to run it under Mono and use the exact same certificate that I was using in Windows, I get a System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException with the text "Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate."

Is there a bug in Mono, or do I just need to do something different to make loading a certificate cross platform?  Just a little test function like this will show the error:

```
public X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(string certPath)
{
    X509Certificate2 signingCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath);

    return signingCertificate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24172972/2555046. Which should be fixed by now, so running the same code you have above shouldn't cause a problem.

Currently I can load .pfx certs on CentOS 6.5 with and without passwords, but no luck with .p12 certs.