# Using X509Certificate2 on Mono - loading with both public and private key?

Tags: c#, mono, x509certificate2

Right now, I try instantiating an X509Certificate2 like this:

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(Resources.cred);
```

Where `Resources.cred` is a `byte[]` representing a *.pfx* file.
This works absolutely fine on Windows/.NET.

However, running the same code under *Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)* (Mono on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS), I get the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for <snipped irrelevant type name> ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of relevant stack trace ---
```

Should it matter, this certificated is signed with my own CA, and is used in raw RSA.

I have the *.pfx*, *.cer* and *.pvk* files available for this certificate.
How must I proceed to load this certificate with the private key under Mono?

Comment: Q1: Is your PKCS#12 file protected with password? Q2: Did you try saving the byte[] into the file and using X509Certificate2(string) constructor?

Comment: A1: No. I actually got a "file not found" exception when I used a password (on Windows; password was correct [copy-pasted]; used `byte[]`, not string), so I removed the password; A2: That will be a pain in the rear due to my deployment habits but I shall test right now.

Comment: Oh, bollocks. It works when using a file. However, I really have to use a `byte[]` because I need the certificate embedded in the assembly.

Comment: Can you use third party library i.e. [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)?

Comment: This seems overkill for fixing just one constructor, but I will if I must... Will this provide me with a `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` instance specifically? I'm actually passing this on to a third-party library, which needs this specifically...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This constructor throws an exception:

```
byte[] pkcs12 = ...;
X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2(pkcs12);
```

This constructor works:

```
byte[] pkcs12 = ...;
X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2(pkcs12, string.Empty);
```

This seems to be a bug so I am going to fix it and send patch to the upstream developers. I will let you know of the progress.

Comment: I've just sent a fix as a [github pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1101) for mono repository.